# Varnish cache throwing 'Error 400 Bad Request'

Tags: http, varnish

I am running a varnish 3.0 server with nginx/php-fpm/wordpress behind it at http://www.whatsthatbug.com.  Most folks seem to be able to get to the site just fine. But I have one visitor who is getting the 400 error from FireFox.

What she got was:
Error 400 Bad Request

Bad Request
Guru Meditation:

XID: 1237423987

Is there anything I can do with that XID to search with varnishlog for more info? Has anyone else had this error using varnish? Or can point me in a generally useful direction to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: did you get a solution?

Answer (score 1):

this might be of some help

https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/Varnishlog

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 200
```

because of this the [range header DoS vulnerability of Apache](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2011/Aug/301)? Then the reason for your error is, that the cookie length of your one visitor is longer than 200 chars! Ask your visitor to request the page without cookies and extend LimitRequestFieldSize

```
LimitRequestFieldSize 300
```

Comment: I did not add LimitRequestFieldSize. I'm using Nginx and PHP-FPM behind the Varnish cache.